# Ajax not filling target DIV correctly after form submit

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to implement a form plugin for a website I have. It is supposed to be very simple, but it refuses to behave like I want.

It's a simple php email form inside a div, that once correctly submitted, is replaced by a success or failure message inside that same div. For now my JS just adds the message on top of the form.

I am stunned because I thought I tackled some serious trouble for my experience doing this, but I can't get past this simple bug. All I want is the response message inside the DIV once contained the form.

**Here's the include PHP:**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['sender']) && isset($_REQUEST['message'])) {//if "sender" and "message" is filled out, proceed

    //check if the email address is invalid
    $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['sender']);
    if ($mailcheck==FALSE) {
        echo "An error has occurred" . $_REQUEST['sender'] . " " . $_REQUEST['message'];
    }
    else {//send email
        $email = $_REQUEST['sender'] ;
        $subject = "This is the subject" ;
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
        mail("myself@gmail.com", $subject, $message, "From: $email" );
        echo "Your message was sent";
    }

}

function createForm($formID, $formName) {
    echo "<div id=\"" . $formID . "\" class=\"ajaxForm\" >" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<form name =\"" . $formName . "\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"ajaxUpdate(\"" . $formID . "\",\"sandbox.php\"," . sender . "," . message . ");>" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<input name=\"sender\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"email\" required><br>" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<textarea rows=\"6\" cols=\"40\" name=\"message\" placeholder=\"message\" required></textarea><br>" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Send\" >" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "</form>" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "</div>" . PHP_EOL;
}


function spamcheck($field) {
    //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
    //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
    $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    //filter_var() validates the e-mail
    //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
    if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**And the ajaxUpdate JS:**

```
function ajaxUpdate(targetDIV, responsePHP, param1, param2) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(targetDIV).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var strContent = responsePHP + "?sender=" + param1 + "&message=" + param2;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", strContent, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I use this by including the js and php, and spawning a form using the createForm() function.

Please some help..

Comment: Basically, it is a case of missing the toilet..

Comment: btw I know that this js function is a big security failure, it just stays like this to be simple right now.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. What `div` do you mean and why you can't get it?

Comment: The DIV that will contain the php response (solicited by the js) is the one with the id=$formID. By creating and passing that around I can have multiple form instances..

Comment: Honestly I can't get it. Your code lacks the part where it should show what do you want to get as result. Maybe this is why nobody came to answer you. I think it's better to explain this sentence `All I want is the response message inside the DIV once contained the form.` specifically.

Comment: There is a "that" missing, "the DIV that once contained the form". Sorry, english is not my native language.

Well I have the createForm echo the html for a form. Then the onsubmit calls the JS function "ajaxUpdate", that calls back the php, gets a response (for example: "An error has occurred"), and proceeds to fill the wrapper DIV that once contained the form with that response. The problem is that it doesn't replace the contents of that DIV, instead spits it out on the <body> before the div..

Did this help? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
echo "<form name =\"" . $formName . "\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"ajaxUpdate(\"" . $formID . "\",\"sandbox.php\"," . sender . "," . message . ");>" . PHP_EOL;
```

You have to use single quotes in function call:

```
echo "<form name =\"" . $formName . "\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"ajaxUpdate('" . $formID . "','sandbox.php','" . sender . "','" . message . "');\">" . PHP_EOL;
```

For preventing submission you can just return `false`:

```
echo "<form name =\"" . $formName . "\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"ajaxUpdate('" . $formID . "','sandbox.php','" . sender . "','" . message . "');return false;\">" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I guess the problem is related to not having anything prevent the default form submit. As I am not using jQuery (and don't wan't), how can I implement it myself?

Comment: Thanks!! That's it! The web is infested with jQuery solutions, thank you ;)